# Javascript: Compare 2 values in loop sorted array

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, for-loop

I can't find an answer for this issue, I'm trying to find the next value in a sorted array, here is my code:

```
 for (i = 0; i < arrayKeys.length; i++) {
   var records = myContacts[arrayKeys[i]];
   // Sort each names
   records = records.sort(sortNames);
   // Now, Lets run over the sorted array
   for (var r_key in records) {
     // If we have the same name more then once we will add the phone number for both of them
     var sphone = (records[r_key].name==records[r_key+1].name) ? true : false; //That's wrong to put here +1
     var rname=records[r_key].name;
     if (sphone) {
       var sphone = " - " + records[r_key].pNumber; // Adding the phone number
     } else sphone = "";                      
     console.log(rname+sphone);
   }
 }
```

**For Example, The Result can be:**

- Benny
- John
- Michel - 0378766667
- Michel - 0365556664
- Vlad
- ...

So, How can i compare The current value with the next one, And add to both names the phone number?

Comment: with the current approach whats the problem ? any syntactical error in firebug console ?

Comment: for - in loops shouldn't be used on arrays

Comment: I don't get the question. If your current array item is a[k] then the next one (if existing) is a[k+1].

Comment: The problem is that it sorted BEFORE the for loop, So i don't know what will be the next one... Thanks